# why the disabled field of the mat-checkbox component may not work

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, angular-material

I need this component to accept the disabled value depending on the variable, the most common use of a component. But it does not work, I did everything as in the documentation

I imported the module as in the documentation, the component itself works[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azS7o.png)
[but field with disabled doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4z69.png)
it doesn't matter if disabled is set through a variable, or through true - nothing
Ыetting disabled form formGroup works, but i can't enter a specific condition there

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, when using reactive forms, you should disable the form control / form group rather than using the `disabled` attribute on the element. There should be a warning about this in the browser console.

Comment: console hasn't warnings.
isDistrPeriod: new FormControl({ value: false, disabled: true }), - this code disabled the component, but condition doesn't work

Comment: I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6qxrpx?file=src%2Fmain.ts) with exactly your scenario, and as you can see there, it throws a warning. You are mixing reactive and template driven approach, this is not recommended and can lead to unexpected results like you are seeing.

Comment: It works like this : this.service.addForm.controls.isDistrPeriod.disable(); - We track the change in the parameter, and when changing, we already set conditions with this method

Answer (score 0):

It works like this : this.service.addForm.controls.isDistrPeriod.disable(); - We track the change in the parameter, and when changing, we already set conditions with this method